# Command failed due to signal: Killed: 9 when archiving

Tags: ios, sigkill

I created an app for iOS Swift and was able to run it on the simulator as well as on the actual device.

However, when I tried to archive the app to be published on the App Store, the following error message was encountered:

> Command failed due to signal: killed: 9

Why was this error encountered and how do I resolve this?

Comment: Is that reproducible? Seems like a process got shut down hard by you, your admin or the system.

Comment: Yes, it's reproducible. It happens each time I try to archive it.

Comment: What is your environment? If it's corporate, there might be a watchdog killing off high-CPU or high-memory tasks.

Comment: I'm running it on my personal iMac

Comment: for swift 3 please review:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39632975/xcode-8-swift-3-command-failed-due-to-signal-killed-9